# Поиск адреса ошибки в map-файле

Tags: delphi, отладка, поиск, адрес

Прочитал описание map-файла https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Map_Debug_File и https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Detailed-Segments_Map_File

начал копаться в map-файле программы и так и не понял как в нём найти адрес указанный в ошибке что бы найти место в исходнике...

сделал тестовый проект:

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

var
  x: integer;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    WriteLn('hello');
  x := 10;
  WriteLn(x / 0) // специально допущенная ошибка
  except
  end;
end.
```

получил ошибку
`Project test.exe raised exception class $C000008E with message 'floating point divide by zero at 0x007a19d8'.`
к чему относится данный класс ошибки **$C000008E**
в map-файле такого класса нет (или чего то не дочитал)

скомпилировал с map-файлом:

```
 Start         Length     Name                   Class
 0001:00401000 0000A038H .text                   CODE
 0002:0040C000 0000019CH .itext                  ICODE
 0003:0040D000 00000A78H .data                   DATA
 0004:0040E000 00003590H .bss                    BSS
 0005:00000000 00000008H .tls                    TLS
 0006:00400000 00000000H .pdata                  PDATA
 
 Detailed map of segments
 0001:00000000 00008F70 C=CODE     S=.text    G=(none)   M=System   ACBP=A9
 0001:00008F70 00000C9C C=CODE     S=.text    G=(none)   M=SysInit  ACBP=A9
 0001:00009C0C 0000042C C=CODE     S=.text    G=(none)   M=test     ACBP=A9
 0002:00000000 000000EC C=ICODE    S=.itext   G=(none)   M=System   ACBP=A9
 0002:000000EC 00000008 C=ICODE    S=.itext   G=(none)   M=SysInit  ACBP=A9
 0002:000000F4 000000A8 C=ICODE    S=.itext   G=(none)   M=test     ACBP=A9
 0003:00000000 000009F4 C=DATA     S=.data    G=DGROUP   M=System   ACBP=A9
 0003:000009F4 0000007C C=DATA     S=.data    G=DGROUP   M=SysInit  ACBP=A9
 0004:00000000 00003568 C=BSS      S=.bss     G=DGROUP   M=System   ACBP=A9
 0004:00003568 00000024 C=BSS      S=.bss     G=DGROUP   M=SysInit  ACBP=A9
 0004:0000358C 00000004 C=BSS      S=.bss     G=DGROUP   M=test     ACBP=A9
 0005:00000000 00000008 C=TLS      S=.tls     G=(none)   M=System   ACBP=A9

 
 Address        Publics by Name
 0001:00009BB8       SysInit...
 0001:00009B78       SysInit...
 0001:00009B48       SysInit...
 0001:00009BEC       SysInit...
 0001:00009B34       SysInit...
 0001:00009B24       SysInit...
 0001:00009B14       SysInit...
 0001:00009B04       SysInit...
 0001:00009AF4       SysInit...
 0003:00000A1C       SysInit...
 0001:00009AE4       SysInit...
 0001:00009B90       SysInit...
 0001:00009BDC       SysInit...
 0004:00003580       SysInit..1
 0001:00008FD0       SysInit.@DelayLoadHelper2
 0001:00009074       SysInit.@GetTls
 0001:000095E0       SysInit.@InitExe
 .
 .
 .
 
 Address        Publics by Value
 0001:0000036C       System..TObject
 0001:00000C0C       System..TCustomAttribute
 0001:00000CAC       System..VolatileAttribute
 0001:000010C0       System.CloseHandle
 0001:000010C8       System.GetStdHandle
 0001:000010D0       System.CreateFile
 0001:000010D8       System.GetFileSize
 0001:000010E0       System.GetFileType
 0001:000010E8       System.ReadFile
 0001:000010F0       System.SetEndOfFile
 0001:000010F8       System.SetFilePointer
 0001:00001100       System.WriteFile
 0001:00001108       System.InitializeCriticalSection
 0001:00001110       System.DeleteCriticalSection
 0001:00001118       System.GetCurrentThreadId
 0001:00001120       System.SwitchToThread
 0001:00001128       System.ExitProcess
 0001:00001130       System.RaiseException
 0001:00001138       System.RtlUnwind
 .
 .
 .
 
 Line numbers for test(test.dpr) segment .itext

    13 0002:000000F4    14 0002:0000010F    16 0002:0000011D    17 0002:00000136
    18 0002:00000140    22 0002:00000174    23 0002:00000179

Bound resource files

test.res
test.drf


Program entry point at 0002:000000F4
```

как по полученному в ошибке адресу найти место возникновения ошибки?

не могу ни как понять откуда вообще начинать вести подсчёт

вообще адрес ошибки указан в адресном пространстве программы или системы?

Comment: у меня в одном из проектов возникла ошибка... адрес есть, а вот действия связанные с появление этой ошибки ни как не получается (на стенде) повторить, вот и начал копаться в отладочной информации... но снова затык, не могу понять как найти место на которое указывает адрес, мне бы соотнести стартовый адрес (нулевой) программы с её реальным адресом в памяти, может быть тогда  стало бы понятнее

Comment: Посмотрите как работает [парсер map файлов в mormot](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynLog.pas#L114), а лучше воспользуйтесь готовыми решениями типа madExcept/EurekaLog.

Comment: @zed посмотрел, не нашёл только откуда взялась функция Memory, относительно неё там происходит сдвиг адресации

Comment: @woojin [Вот здесь](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/c-reading-memory-from-exe-offset/) написано что адрес приложения возвращается функцией [GetModuleHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlew). С нюансами.

Comment: @woojin Если вы вот про [этот](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynLog.pas#L1870) участок кода, то там чуть выше есть конструкция `with TSynMemoryStreamMapped.Create(...) do` - вот у этого класса и вызывается метод Memory.

Comment: @zed да именно про этот участок, спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В map файле указаны относительные адреса, в то время как в сообщении об ошибке указывается абсолютный адрес в памяти процесса где возникла ошибка.

Для перевода, из абсолютного адреса нужно вычесть две величины:

- базовый адрес процесса (Image Base Address), который обычно равен `$400000`, но может быть произвольным (например, из-за ASLR);
- смещение сегмента кода, которое обычно равно `$1000`, но так же может быть иным (можно посмотреть в PE заголовках или в map файле).

Получив относительный адрес, вам нужно будет найти **ближайшие** (в меньшую сторону) адреса функции и номера строки в map файле.

---

Пример:

```
program SynLogTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  SynLog,
  SynCommons;

procedure DoInit;
begin
  with TSynLog.Family do begin
    Level := LOG_VERBOSE;
    EchoToConsole := LOG_VERBOSE;
    //NoFile := True;
  end;
  TSynLog.Add.Log(sllInfo, SynCommons.SYNOPSE_FRAMEWORK_FULLVERSION);
  TSynLog.Add.Log(sllInfo, 'Base Address: 0x' + IntToHex(GetModuleHandle(nil), 8));
end;

procedure DoTest;
begin
  try
    Writeln(ParamCount/0);
  except
    //
  end;
end;

begin
  DoInit;
  DoTest;
  try
    Writeln(ParamCount/0);
  except
    //
  end;

  Writeln('Press [ENTER] to exit...');
  Readln;
end.
```

Вывод в логе:

```
info  Base Address: 0x005D0000
EXCOS EInvalidOp (c0000090) [] at 6fefe7 SynLogTest.DoTest (25)  stack trace API 
EXCOS EInvalidOp (c0000090) [] at 7045d5  stack trace API
```

Вычисляем первый адрес: `$6fefe7 - $5D0000 - $1000 = $12DFE7`

Смотрим в map файл:

```
 0001:0012DE24       SynLogTest.DoInit
 0001:0012DFC0       SynLogTest.DoTest
 0001:0012E01C       SynLogTest.Finalization

Line numbers for SynLogTest(SynLogTest.dpr) segment .text

    12 0001:0012DE24    13 0001:0012DE40    14 0001:0012DE72    15 0001:0012DE82
    18 0001:0012DE92    19 0001:0012DEDA    20 0001:0012DF48    23 0001:0012DFC0
    24 0001:0012DFC7    25 0001:0012DFD5    28 0001:0012E00E    29 0001:0012E013
```

- находим ближайшую функцию с меньшим адресом: `0012DFC0 SynLogTest.DoTest`
- находим ближайший номер строки с меньшим адресом: `25 0001:0012DFD5`

Comment: отличное разъяснение! то что нужно!